# Change value in filtered row to filtered value of another row

Tags: python, pandas

I am automating a large Excel process and I cannot figure out how to change a row's value based on another row when both of them are filtered. I created a sample dataframe to demonstrate this issue.

```
data = {'Category': ['WC', 'WC', 'GL', 'WC', 'WC', 'WC', 'WC'],
        'Year': [2024, 2023, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2021, 2022],
        'Type': ['Direct', 'QS', 'Direct', 'Direct', 'QS', 'Direct', 'Direct'],
        'Code': [1450, 1450, 2000, 1450, 1450, 1500, 1450],
        'Total': [9, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Creates the data frame the looks like this:

```
Category  Year    Type  Code  Total
0       WC  2024  Direct  1450      9
1       WC  2023      QS  1450      3
2       GL  2022  Direct  2000      5
3       WC  2023  Direct  1450      7
4       WC  2024      QS  1450      2
5       WC  2021  Direct  1500      4
6       WC  2022  Direct  1450      6
```

What I want change is I want the total value in the direct row to be twice the value of the total column in the QS for the respective years while being filtered on the filters I have in the below code. So, the new data frame would look like this:

```
 Category  Year    Type  Code  Total
0       WC  2024  Direct  1450      4
1       WC  2023      QS  1450      3
2       GL  2022  Direct  2000      5
3       WC  2023  Direct  1450      6
4       WC  2024      QS  1450      2
5       WC  2023  Direct  1500      4
6       WC  2022  Direct  1450      6
```

To achieve this result, I tried using this code:

```
WCdf = df[(df.Category == 'WC') & (df.Year > 2022) & (df.Code == 1450) & (df.Type == 'QS')]
df.loc[(df['Code'] == 1450) & (df['Category'] == 'WC') & (df['Year'] > 2022) & (df['Type'] == 'Direct'), 'Total'] = 2 * WCdf.Total
```

The WCdf does have the correct rows in it, but when I use this code, it just turns the values I want changed to NaN. I am not exactly sure how to achieve the results I am looking for given the restraints. I think I may not be able to use the .loc function in this case, but I am not sure what I would use instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
# create a dictionary with new Total values
m = {row["Year"]: row["Total"] * 2 for _, row in df[df["Type"].eq("QS")].iterrows()}

# apply the new Total values in rows with Type == "Direct"
mask = df["Type"].eq("Direct")
df.loc[mask, "Total"] = df[mask].apply(lambda x: m.get(x["Year"], x["Total"]), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Category  Year    Type  Code  Total
0       WC  2024  Direct  1450      4
1       WC  2023      QS  1450      3
2       GL  2022  Direct  2000      5
3       WC  2023  Direct  1450      6
4       WC  2024      QS  1450      2
```

---

EDIT: With additional conditions:

```py
m = {row["Year"]: row["Total"] * 2 for _, row in df[df["Type"].eq("QS")].iterrows()}

mask = df["Type"].eq("Direct") & (df["Year"] > 2022) & (df["Code"] == 1450)
df.loc[mask, "Total"] = df[mask].apply(lambda x: m.get(x["Year"], x["Total"]), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This does work for this dataset, but for the actual one I need to also filter the code to 1450 and the year to be after 2022. I should have made that clearer in the dataset. I tried messing around with your code, but I cannot seem to figure out how to do this as I am getting various errors. How do I do multiple conditions for this with one of them being a greater than condition?

Comment: @SaicheS Please [edit] your question and put the sample input there + expected output.

Comment: I added two rows to the data. One that I do not want because it does not have the code 1450 and one that has 1450 but is before 2023.  If it makes things simpler, there is no QS for ones that do not meet that requirement like shown in the dataset, so the direct entries with no QS must stay unchanged for now.

Comment: @SaicheS See my edit, I've put additional conditions to the `mask`